# Browser not caching content

Tags: php, apache, caching, http-headers, lamp

I am using a LAMP system on Ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to cache the content of my webpage for some time.

First I tried to add the following to the top of my php page

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=60, public');
?>
```

When I check the Response header I get the following
    Cache-Control: max-age=60, public, max-age=1

I think it is due to some setting in Apache that max-age=1 gets set. So the header looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 06:42:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public, max-age=1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 06:42:21 GMT
Content-Length: 12725
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

So to check, I put the following in php

```
<?php
header('Expires: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT');
?>
```

I get the following Response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 14:11:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
Expires: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 12755
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

You can see from the above Response header that Expires is set to more than Current server time.

When I refresh the browser I see a different page so browser is not caching the page

Can anyone of you let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: someone please answer the question

Comment: Does the browser send a conditional request? If so, what's the response?